# How to retrieve Sharepoint Apps from SiteContents

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-apps

Iam using Sharepoint.Client library(using context - ClientContext, load & then execute) to pull metadata from SP.Web. I was able to fetch some details except the one that i required the most: "APPS". How to pull apps that installed in SP ? 
There's a solution from REST API part:
https:///_api/web/webinfos?$filter=(WebTemplate eq "APP")
But I need to pull down these from my Client Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reference link: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70628/get-list-of-installed-apps-using-client-object-model

You can go through this link and it will help you to get SharePoint apps using Client Library (CSOM).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I cannot find App Icon in the AppCatalog instances :(